# Time series Prediction as a multi-output multivariate regression for many input and output values for each lag

Tags: time-series, multivariate-regression

Recently I am working on time series prediction. My topic is related to wind turbine blades which has many sections in each blade. Now we want to predict some performance and metrics of 51 sections of 10 blades(each section has different values and different behavior) and here we have 22 inputs and 3 targets. All the data has been collected during 600 seconds. So, we have many information in every second.
I want to use multi-out regression algorithms like MGPR, MSVR, MGHPR and then find the coefficient of predictors for each target for each time per seconds and then use time series prediction like LSTM for all 600 seconds to predict 3 targets for 600 next seconds.
Please help me that my procedure is right or not?

Answer (score 0):

http://autobox.com/dave/regvsbox.pdf (which I authored) discusses issues/differences/opportunities/pitfalls when dealing with time series that your possible regression solutions may be ignoring. Time series data can suggest lag structures for input series AND lag structure for the series that is being predicted while identifying the presence/form of external deterministic effects (level shifts,local time trends,seasonal pulses,pulses) while addressing the effect of non-constant model error variance and non-constant model parameters over time.

Whether or not you are predicting 1 series at a time using multivariate inputs or predicting multiple series at a time using multivariate inputs one needs to be aware of the assumptions under which estimation proceeds and how these assumptions are tested via model diagnostics,

Comment: Could you clarify how your post addresses the special *multivariate* aspect of this question?  In its current form it reads like vague boilerplate rather than a specific answer.

Comment: hope I cleared that up

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. Unfortunately, I am so beginner in Time Series Prediction. Could you please suggest me some references to be more clear how to do my research?